# Arrays in C programming language

Tags: c

I am a beginner in the C programing language and so I need an explanation for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int NUM[10];
    int i,index;


    for(i=0 ; i<8 ; i++){

        NUM[index]=i;

        index++;
    }


    printf("this is the number %d\n\n",NUM);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
this is the number 6356704
```

Why the number in the console is not correct?

Comment: `index` is uninitialised, so its value is indeterminate.   Accessing its value therefore gives undefined behaviour.    Using it as an array index (the first thing done with it in assigning to `NUM[index]`) and incrementing it (`index++`) both work by accessing the value of `index`.    Initialise `index` to a valid value (e.g. `0`) before the loop.    Also, `NUM` is an array, not a single `int`.   Printing it with the `%d` tells `printf()` to *assume* `NUM` is an `int` when it is not (i.e. there is a type mismatch) so the `printf()` statement also has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("this is the number %d\n\n",NUM);` passes `NUM` to `printf` to be formatted with the `%d` conversion specifier.

`NUM` is an array. In this use, it is automatically converted to the address of its first element. `%d` expects an `int` to be passed. An address is not an `int`. Because of this mismatch, the behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard. At best, the `printf` will print the address formatted in decimal.

To print the elements of the arrays, you must write a loop that prints each element, as by passing `NUM[i]` to `printf` to be formatted with `%d`. You could use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    printf("NUM[%d] = %d.\n", i, NUM[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is VERY unclear what you're trying to do. But if you want to print the elements inside an array, you can't write a single printf statement and expect to get the elements printed out in order for you.

To print the elements of an array in order, you will have to use a for loop to do it. Something like this-

```
for (i=0; i<8; i++) 
{
     printf("%d", num[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a number of issues here.  To begin, you initialize an integer area (NUM), and then you attempt to print it at the end.  Also, you initialize i, but you don't initialize index.  This will cause the values that are populating NUM to be different from what you expect because your starting point is "garbage."

Below I've included a slightly modified version.  Notice that after index is initialized, I assign it a value so that the starting point is zero like `i`.  I made a slight modification in the loop, I have `for(i=0; i < sizeof(NUM)/sizeof(NUM[0]); i++)`.  The only difference here, is instead of iterating an arbitrary number of times (8 in your case), I iterate through the loop based on the total length of the array (in bytes) divided by the length of each element (in bytes) which yields the total number of integers that it contains.  I then print each element of the area as it's assigned with `printf("this is the number %d\n\n",NUM[i]);`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int NUM[10];
    int i,index;
    index = 0;

    for(i=0 ; i < sizeof(NUM)/sizeof(NUM[0]); i++){
        NUM[index]=i;
        printf("this is the number %d\n\n",NUM[i]);
        index++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```